# Error Starting Windows Driver: The handle is invalid

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, wdk

I am a web developer that decided to venture into kernel mode development. I installed WDK 8.1, Visual Studio Professional 2013 and I set up a Windows 7 VM to debug and test my drivers.

I started with [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx)

I download the solution and build the driver. I wasn’t able to do the deployment steps described in the tutorial so I tried to install the driver using the [OSR Driver Loader](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=157)

I was able to register the driver but when I try to start it I get the following error.

C:\Windows\system32>sc start KmfSmall

[SC]  StartService FAILED 6:

The handle is invalid.

This is the driver's code:

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>

DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD KmdfSmallEvtDeviceAdd;

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;

    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfSmall: DriverEntry\n"));
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config, KmdfSmallEvtDeviceAdd);
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject, RegistryPath, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &config, WDF_NO_HANDLE);
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS KmdfSmallEvtDeviceAdd(_In_ WDFDRIVER Driver, _Inout_ PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDFDEVICE hDevice;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfSmall: KmdfSmallEvtDeviceAdd\n"));
    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &hDevice);
    return status;
}
```

Comment: The OSR tool is from 2008 and almost certainly doesn't suit KMDF driver built with WDK8.1. You should follow the MS tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I just answered what appears to be the same problem after spending a week or so trying to figure it out.

Basically boils down to the project settings missing the KMDF version.

Question: [Why am I getting Error Code 6 on StartService?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13254487/2487257)
Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23705329/2487257

Comment: Should be marked as answer, setting KMDF version to 1.9 helped in my case.